# IonPicker Showing wrong values

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm making an Ionic App that shows the selected text of an options array, I'm using the ion-picker component(not so much documentation on the internet), everything works fine, when I console.log the value of the index it shows the right value in the console, I'm using an alert as well to show the selected value as a part of the message, but when i select for example the first value the alert shows no value, then if i select the second value the alert shows the first value, i dont understand whats happening with this because the console.log has the correct value.

These are my two functions.

```js
async selectHora() {
    const times: PickerOptions = {
      cssClass: 'horasSelect',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancelar',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'btnCancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Confirmar',
          handler: (value) => {
            value = this.horaSeleccionada;
            console.log('confirmacion', this.horaSeleccionada);
            this.confirmacion(value);
          }
        }
      ],
      columns: [
        {
          name: 'Horas',
          options: [
            {text: '8:00 - 9:00', value: 1},
            {text: '9:00 - 10:00', value: 2},
            {text: '10:00 - 11:00', value: 3},
            {text: '11:00 - 12:00', value: 4},
            {text: '12:00 - 13:00', value: 5},
            {text: '13:00 - 14:00', value: 6},
            {text: '14:00 - 15:00', value: 7},
            {text: '15:00 - 16:00', value: 8},
            {text: '16:00 - 17:00', value: 9},
            {text: '17:00 - 18:00', value: 10}
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
    const picker = await this.picker.create(times);
    picker.present();
    picker.onDidDismiss().then(async data => {
      const col = await picker.getColumn('Horas');
      console.log('Esta es la columna ', col);
      this.horaSeleccionada = col.options[col.selectedIndex].value;
      console.log(this.horaSeleccionada);
      // this.confirmacion();
    });
  }

async confirmacion(value) {
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: 'Confirmación Pedido',
      subHeader: 'Si desea cambiar la hora, seleccione cancelar',
        message: 'Su pedido será entregado entre las ' + value,
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'OK',
            handler: () => {
              console.log('ok texto', this.horaSeleccionada);
              // this.router.navigateByUrl('/orderfinished');
            }
          }
        ],
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hi i have resolved your issue

[stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-wqzdpy)

**Error**

```
value = this.horaSeleccionada;
```

**Correct way**

```
this.horaSeleccionada =value;
```

Working example

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

import { PickerController } from '@ionic/angular';

export interface PickerOptions {
  buttons?: any[];
  columns?: any[];
  cssClass?: string;
  mode?: string;
  enableBackdropDismiss?: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
   horaSeleccionada:any;
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private alertCtrl:AlertController,
    private picker:PickerController
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.selectHora(); 
    });
  }

  async selectHora() {

    const times: PickerOptions = {
      cssClass: 'horasSelect',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancelar',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'btnCancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Confirmar',
          handler: (value) => {
             this.horaSeleccionada=value;
            console.log('confirmacion',  this.horaSeleccionada);
            this.confirmacion(value);
          }
        }
      ],
      columns: [
        {
          name: 'Horas',
          options: [
            {text: '8:00 - 9:00', value: 1},
            {text: '9:00 - 10:00', value: 2},
            {text: '10:00 - 11:00', value: 3},
            {text: '11:00 - 12:00', value: 4},
            {text: '12:00 - 13:00', value: 5},
            {text: '13:00 - 14:00', value: 6},
            {text: '14:00 - 15:00', value: 7},
            {text: '15:00 - 16:00', value: 8},
            {text: '16:00 - 17:00', value: 9},
            {text: '17:00 - 18:00', value: 10}
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
    const picker = await this.picker.create(times);
    picker.present();
    picker.onDidDismiss().then(async data => {
      const col = await picker.getColumn('Horas');
      console.log('Esta es la columna ', col);
      this.horaSeleccionada = col.options[col.selectedIndex].value;
      console.log(this.horaSeleccionada);
      // this.confirmacion();
    });
  }

async confirmacion(value) {
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
      header: 'Confirmación Pedido',
      subHeader: 'Si desea cambiar la hora, seleccione cancelar',
        message: 'Su pedido será entregado entre las ' + value,
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'OK',
            handler: () => {
              console.log('ok texto', this.horaSeleccionada);
              // this.router.navigateByUrl('/orderfinished');
            }
          }
        ],
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm getting a result now, but the thing now the result is [object Object], I've tried converting it to a JSON object, but not answer. I tried saving the index on another variable, but the result shows "undefined"

Comment: simply add console.log(JSON.stringify(this.horaSeleccionada));-------JSON.stringify

Comment: This works perfectly, I found another solution on my own, turns out the handler of the Ok and Confirm buttons, recieves an event, so just with the event was enough to make it show the correct value, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems you assigning the variable wrong way `value = this.horaSeleccionada;` **wrong** `this.horaSeleccionada = value` **correct** can you check it & let me know if its working